# Kendo UI Editor inside Kendo Window

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-window, kendo-editor

I am using a `kendo-editor` for WYSIWYG text editing and works great. But when the `kendo-editor` is *inside* a `kendo-window` I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null
    at Widget.extend._createContentElement (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.editor.js?:426:16)
    at Widget.extend._initializeContentElement (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.editor.js?:512:40)
    at new Widget.extend.init (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.editor.js?:282:18)
    at HTMLTextAreaElement.eval (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.core.js?:3104:32)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.each (webpack:///../Scripts/jquery.js?:374:23)
    at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (webpack:///../Scripts/jquery.js?:139:17)
    at $.fn.(anonymous function) [as kendoEditor] (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.core.js?:3103:26)
    at createIt (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.angular.js?:192:31)
    at createWidget (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.angular.js?:168:20)
    at link (webpack:///./kendo-ui/js/kendo.angular.js?:681:34)
```

occuring in **kendo.editor.js**.

```
iframe = $("<iframe />", { title: editor.options.messages.editAreaTitle, frameBorder: "0" })[0];

$(iframe)
    .css("display", "")
    .addClass("k-content")
    .insertBefore(textarea);


iframe.src = src;

wnd = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
doc = wnd.document || iframe.contentDocument;

$(iframe).one("load", function() {
    editor.toolbar.decorateFrom(doc.body);
});

doc.open(); // throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of null
doc.write(
```

Note there's no error and it works great when the `kendo-editor` is not inside the `kendo-window`.

Has anyone ever run into something like this and what's a solution / workaround?

Comment: Are you sure your kendo editor is set up AFTER the kendo window is created? If not try to call kendoEditor (or the object to bind to) in the event "open" of kendoWindow

Comment: this was the issue. feel free to add as answer, I shall accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kendo Editor instance should be called after the kendo Window has been opened, in other words after its container is in the DOM.

You should create the kendoEditor in the open event:

```
$("<div/>").kendoWindow({
  open: function(e){
    $("#myTextarea").kendoEditor();
  }
});
```